# Turning a filename into a global variable in R

Tags: r

I have a function that imports an excel file specified by the user and turns it into a global variable "a":

```
library(tcltk)
library(readxl)

getXlsx <- function() {
  xlsheet <- tclvalue(tkgetOpenFile(
    filetypes = "{ {Excel Files} {.xlsx} } { {All Files} * }"))
  a <- read_excel(xlsheet)
  assign("a", a, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

I need a command I can add to this function to create another global variable with the name/path of the file that was imported.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe, the `xlsheet` variable in your function is the file path of the excel file. Simply use `assign` as for `a` to make a global variable.

Comment: `assign("filepath_for_a", xlsheet, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Thank you guys.  I simply had to add: assign("z", xlsheet, envir = .GlobalEnv).  This made the file path a value "z" in the global environment.